# How to Encode a HexString to Base64 RFC 1421 in Java

Tags: java, string, base64, hex, converters

I need to do a conversion from Hexadecimal String to Base64 in RFC 1421 format. So far I have been doing it with:

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
```

But reading the documentation it says the following: *Provides Base64 encoding and decoding as defined by RFC 2045.*

Therefore it doesn't work for me, I have tried to look for examples to convert a Hex String to Base64 RFC 1421 in Java, but I can't find anything.

Can you give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.
A greeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `java.util.Base64` class (available since java 8)?

It has a [`getMimeEncoder(int, byte[])` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html#getMimeEncoder(int,byte%5B%5D)) which you can use with a `lineLength` of 64 and the resulting `Encoder` should be RFC1421 compliant:

```
Encoder rfc1421 = Base64.getMimeEncoder(64, new byte[] {'\r', '\n'});
```

Note: there may be other specificities that I don't know of.

Comment: Thanks!!, and for Java 7?

Comment: You can use apache commons Base64 library - I think you can specify a length of 64 too.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/net/util/Base64.html#Base64(int)